# BCP to CSV file with commas in the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I have a BCP process that is calling a stored procedure. Typically I have been executing this stored procedure and copying the data to an Excel sheet that I specifed all columns as text and saved this as a CSV.

I need to automate this work and have been playing with the BCP command but so far have an issues. The data I have has commas in it which shifts data to the left. Is this something I can overcome with a format file or something of the sort?

I would rather not quote these in the output of the proc itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The BCP command has the -t switch which specifies the field terminator.  In your case, it is a comma or CHR(44).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

To prevent MS Excel from having issues opening the file, enclose all text fields in the QUERY with double quotes "" or CHR(34).

Here is a sample query from Adventure Works.

```
-- Enclose text w/ possible commas in quotes
select 
  char(34) + AddressLine1 + char(34) as fmt_address_line1,
  char(34) + City + char(34) as fmt_city,
  PostalCode as postal_code
from 
  [AdventureWorks2012].[Person].[Address]
```

This should allow you to open the file in MS Excel w/o any issues.

Comment: Well, "w/o any issues" is a gross overstatement as data can contain `"` (double-quotes) which breaks everything if not dutifully escaped to `""` (double double-quotes).

Comment: That is why big data companies went to structured files like arvo, orc and parquet.  CSV is old school, fragile and does not support advance features like partitioning and compression.  But yes, it is frustrating sometimes to work with CSV.

Comment: Yes, big data companies moved forward while SQL Server is still unable to (easily) export a CSV file, let alone export all tables in a db to a directory as multiple CSV files in one go :-))