# need to write a bcp utility query getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a situation where need to copy form table to any file directly with passing parameter. like server name `user ID`, `password` but I am able to write only the single query without parameter in that also I am facing an error like if I have a `column value is comma separated` then getting the value in `separate column` but I need it in a single column below is the query can anyone help me out?

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT *FROM mydb.dbo.mytable" QUERYOUT C:\test\mytable.csv -c  -t , -T -S'
```

Comment: Are u getting error or Values are in different columns ?. Can u also add column names and sample data please

Comment: Might get information from here -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097978/bcp-to-csv-file-with-commas-in-the-data

Comment: I am getting values in different column ex:if I am getting value in a column like"The address of this account, is not valid, also very it" ---this is the value in comment column and I am getting it in separate column.